# SQL Server / T-SQL: Selecting a specific interval ( group by )

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I want to write a select that aggregates over data (which has a `DATETIME` column as ID) with ANY interval theoretically possible (like 1hr, 1hr and 22seconds, 1year and 3minutes, etc. ).

This select should be able to aggregate by 1hr, 12min, 14seconds and should return 3 rows

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,id) as year, 
        DATEPART(MONTH,id) as month,
        DATEPART(DAY,id) as day,
        DATEPART(HOUR,id) as hour,
        DATEPART(MINUTE,id) as minute,
        AVG([Open]),
        AVG([Close]),
        AVG([Min]),
        AVG([Max])
FROM QuoteHistory
where id between '2000-02-06 17:00:00.000' and '2000-02-06 20:36:42.000'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(YEAR,id), 
    DATEPART(MONTH,id),
    DATEPART(DAY,id),
    DATEPART(HOUR,id),
    DATEPART(MINUTE,id)
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

I am kind of stuck here and can't get my head around this problem.. For "simple intervals" like "30 minutes" i could just add a modulo

```
DATEPART(MINUTE,id)%2
```

but when the interval "touches" more than 1 part of the date, I'm stuck.

Any help appreciated, thx!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you need `GROUP BY ... WITH CUBE` or `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`... Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427.aspx

Comment: Wait, do you want your query to be able to aggregate by the _sum_ of those durations (every hour + 12 minutes + 14 seconds) or show aggregates in the individual time slices (one row every hour, one row every 12 minutes, one row every 14 seconds)?

Comment: no, i mean the "sum".. as stated i want the query to have 3 results (rows)

Comment: I'd expect mixing fixed intervals (like hour, minute) with non-fixed ones (year, month) in this case to be *very* tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some parameters here:

```
;WITH Date_Ranges AS (
    SELECT
        @min_datetime AS start_datetime,
        DATEADD(SECOND, @seconds,
            DATEADD(MINUTE, @minutes,
            DATEADD(HOUR, @hours,
            DATEADD(DAY, @days,
            DATEADD(WEEK, @weeks,
            DATEADD(MONTH, @months,
            DATEADD(YEAR, @years, @min_datetime))))))) AS end_datetime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(SECOND, 1, end_datetime),
        DATEADD(SECOND, @seconds,
            DATEADD(MINUTE, @minutes,
            DATEADD(HOUR, @hours,
            DATEADD(DAY, @days,
            DATEADD(WEEK, @weeks,
            DATEADD(MONTH, @months,
            DATEADD(YEAR, @years, end_datetime)))))))
    FROM
        Date_Ranges
    WHERE
        DATEADD(SECOND, 1, end_datetime) < @max_datetime
)
SELECT
    DR.min_datetime,
    DR.max_datetime,
    AVG([Open]),
    AVG([Close]),
    AVG([Min]),
    AVG([Max])
FROM
    Date_Ranges DR
LEFT OUTER JOIN Quote_History QH ON
    QH.id BETWEEN DR.min_datetime AND DR.max_datetime
GROUP BY
    DR.min_datetime,
    DR.max_datetime
ORDER BY
    DR.min_datetime,
    DR.max_datetime
```

You might need to fiddle with how to handle the edge cases (that 1 second range between date ranges could be a problem depending on your data). This should hopefully point you in the right direction though.